# issues with merging CSS stylesheets?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Essentially, I want to use the [vertical timeline](https://github.com/CodyHouse/vertical-timeline) from CodyHouse in a project hosted on a [Bootstrap template](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-grayscale). I've migrated the HTML content, but the CSS files are causing issues. For example:

- it distorts the navigation bar and header spacing
- there should be a bounce animation for the elements of the timeline - no go.
- I can't see any of the p text of the timeline

How can I edit/arrange the stylesheets appropriately so that the timeline inherits the font/background style of the Bootstrap but maintains the animation from CodyHouse?

Comment: Change the classes of your timeline so they are unique and then you can change the classes from codyhouse to match, that way you will not have existing classes interfering.  Ensure that when you finish the class changes, you are not targeting elements - eg there is nothing blanket targeting a p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda hard to really pinpoint what your issues are with no code offered by you for inspection, but....

You'll really need to use your browser's inspect/page-debug functions on your page to see how both the bootstrap stylesheet and the vertical timeline's stylesheet are doing things to your page.

Bootstrap has it's own default color scheme, you can easily change it by just looking for the corresponding bootstrap elements and then overriding them in your custom stylesheet

If you're linking to three different styles sheets (boostrap, timeline, and your custom one), there can obviously be a conflict right there. Let's say on boostrap it's doing one thing to the nav bar and the top spacing, while your custom css is doing another thing and affect bottom spaces - see what I mean? You should really inspect those css files to see what they are affecting exactly.

**Also, is the vertical timeline plugin you are using based on bootstrap 4? If it's built around bootstrap 3 that could be another issue as well. BS4 is still relatively new and many plugins that were based on BS3 may require further alteration.**

Comment: Thanks - I'm working through the inspect but wasn't sure if there was a quicker way to move through that. It's also not really packaged as a plugin, so I don't think it's meant to work with bootstrap at all. It's primarily the animation I want to bring back, everything else I can figure out/deal with in time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the rules within styles.css ...you'll probably want to remove the generic rules - all those under 'Primary style' and then the first few under 'Resource style' where it makes reference to stuff within header{...}.

Also don't include the other stylesheets, reset.css and demo.css

Comment: just curious, why shouldn't include the other stylesheets?

Comment: Well the reset.css is codyhouse's own version of a reset stylesheet, where bootstrap already has it's own and you might overwrite some values. the demo.css seems to be specific for their own demo page and not relevant to the actual timeline html. They haven't really packaged this properly as a 'plugin'.